# Difference in open()

Tags: c, unix

If we open FIFO with O_NONBLOCK set, why opening with read-only or write-only set, `open()` behave differently?

Comment: cannot make sense of your question...

Comment: I have tried to edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is asymmetry due to communication semantic.

Opening for writing in non blocking mode should fail if there is no reader at that time because writing into a channel with no reader is of no usage (without any reader writing should fail).

Opening for reading in non blocking can succeed (and does) because it declares that somebody will (eventually) be able to read something in the future.